# Adverb use in sentence

Tags: adverbs

Never,ever is it adverb? I have problem with use adverb in a sentence with auxiliary verb.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to EL&U! Could you edit your question, please? Please tell us what you find confusing. Please give some example sentences too. Thanks.